# Getting a Value from a previous Row in DrawColumnCell

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I have a dbGrid filled by a MyDAC-SQL-Query set to RowSelect.
One column contains a location string and there can be multiple rows for each location.

What i want to do is to give a visual feedback to better distinguish between different locations. So the rows with the first location should have a white background and the second a grey one, the third a white, and so on...

[image: example]

I know how to give every second row a different background, but i'm struggeling to detect on which row the location changes.

So, in the `DrawColumnCell` procedure i would like to look at the location value of the previous row to detect the change. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement some logic to store the previous field's value, and to determine whether or not a new  color is necessary.

Here's a quick example of doing so. To set it up, just a few steps are needed - I've started with a new, blank VCL forms application for simplicity.

- Drop a TClientDataSet on the form, and change it's name to CDS.
- Add a TDataSource, and set its DataSet to CDS.
- Next, add a TDBGrid and set its DataSource to DataSource1
- Change the DBGrid.DefaultDrawing to False.
- Add three new variables to the form's `private` section:

  ```
  private
    SameCity, SameColor: Boolean;
    LastCity: string;
  ```
- Add the following code to the form's `OnCreate` event to set up the data and initialize the variables:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    // One field dataset, with the exact same cities and rows
    // you've shown in your question
    CDS.FieldDefs.Add('City', ftString, 10);
    CDS.CreateDataSet;
    for I := 1 to 3 do
      CDS.AppendRecord(['London']);
    for i := 1 to 2 do
      CDS.AppendRecord(['Paris']);
    CDS.AppendRecord(['Berlin']);
    for i := 1 to 2 do
      CDS.AppendRecord(['New York']);
    CDS.Open;

    // Initialize variables for first use
    LastCity := '';
    SameColor := False;
    SameCity := False;
  end;
  ```
- Add an event handler to the DBGrid for the `OnDrawDataCell` event, with the following code:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawDataCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  Field: TField; State: TGridDrawState);
  const
    RowColors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (clWindow, clLtGray);
  begin
    // See if we're on the same city as the last row, and save the
    // value in the current row for use next row.
    SameCity := (Field.AsString = LastCity);
    LastCity := Field.AsString;

    // If they weren't the same, toggle the color value
    if not SameCity then
      SameColor := not SameColor;

    // Set the row color and tell the grid to draw the row
    (Sender as TDBGrid).Canvas.Brush.Color := RowColors[SameColor];
    (Sender as TDBGrid).DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, Field, State);
  end;
  ```

I've used *OnDrawDataCell* instead of *OnDrawColumnCell* because it doesn't get called on the header row or fixed column, so the DBGrid will take care of drawing those completely.

Running the application produces these results.

[image: Grid drawn with colored sets of rows]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately i get an access violation when calling `CDS.CreateDataSet;`

As this is only to populate the grid, i've tried to implement your code into my main project. But `DrawDataCell` is not called...

Comment: 1) You have to drop the ClientDataSet on the form at design-time. 2) You have to set the DBGrid.DefaultDrawing to False. I compiled and ran the code before posting (it's how I got the screen capture), so if you followed the instructions properly it works.

Comment: Well, i did all that. Maybe something is different in our delphi versions? I'm using XE5

Comment: The code works in both D2007 and 10.1 Berlin. (The screen capture was done in Berlin.) Did you start a new, blank VCL forms application and follow the steps I provided?

Comment: Also (sorry if I'm asking the obvious), you *did* use the Object Inspector Events tab to generate the two event handlers and connect them before using the code?

Comment: Yes, its obvious but i would ask the same questions.
I followed the steps from your answer in a new application and used the object inspector to create the events.
Maybe in need to put some units in the uses clause?

Comment: Ok, finally got it to work by including the `MidasLib` into the uses clause.

But now i experience a problem with the coloring: When selecting a row the colors change and don't match anymore.

Comment: You only have to add MidasLib to the uses clause if you're deploying your app and don't want to distribute Midas with your app. As far as selected rows, that's a different topic. I've answered the question you asked here. You have to draw the cell differently when it's selected - that's what you get in the `State` parameter you receive. Draw it however you'd like when `State = dgSelected`.